# return ajax string is 'empty' but cant pin it to 'empty', Why?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with or after I delete files to clear the DataTable.

here is the `.success` bit of my `ajax` call

> ```
>             success: function(data) {
>                 var data = $.trim(data);
>                 alert(data);
>                 if (data == "empty"){
>                     alert("What follows is blank: " + data);
>                 }
>                 else{
>                     alert("What follows is not blank: " + data);
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Now from this I get the first `alert` saying the following.

[image]

Then I run the `if (data == "empty")` bit to see if data is 'empty'

but if continues on its way to the `alert("What follows is not blank: " + data);` alert andd I dont know why.

[image]

Why is this happening. How should I be testing this then?

**PHP RETURN SNIP**

> ```
>     // Fetch all records after edit
>     $json= fetchAll();
>     echo ( sizeof($json) > 0) ? json_encode($json) : json_encode( $json['empty'] = >'empty' );
> ```

Comment: maybe data is exactly `"empty"` and not just `empty`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string contains the `"` symbol at the start and end, so check if the string is equal to `'"empty"'` instead.

Comment: lackOfSurprize = new facePalm();